# Make UITableViewCell editable

Tags: ios, text, uitableview, edit, cells

Given the Detail View in [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH5-SW3), how do I make the cells in the detail view editable?  Not just to add or delete cells, but to modify the text in the cell value (right label in the cell)?

Answer (score 1):

in both your UI and your code, change the UILabel objects to UITextField, hook them up the same way.  they will allow editing of text in those fields.

you will then also have to hook up your viewController to fetch them when the user changes them (via delegate setup) and set up your model to accept the data from your delegate implementation.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pod for that: https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTextFieldTableViewCell

Here's the relevant code:

```
    self.detailTextLabel?.isHidden = true
    self.contentView.viewWithTag(3)?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.textField.tag = 3
    self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.textField)
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -16))
    self.textField.textAlignment = .right
```